# Debian OBS black screen with cursor when screen capture but not on window capture

Tags: linux, debian, obs-studio

I've downloaded obs using apt and I'm trying to screen record.

When I use window capture, it captures just fine. But when I tried to Screen Capture, it just shows a black screen with just my cursor.

I've tried running the app with `obs -platform wayland` command but it just freaks the app out.

I've tried adding `WaylandEnable=false` to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` (which there were no files called custom.conf inside gdm3 but I've created one) to no avail.

I've seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968497/obs-on-ubuntu-17-10-artful-black-screen-only-cursor-in-screen-capture-mode) but it says to log out and log in which I can't seem to find those options. I've also seen some people suggesting enabling `Use alpha-less texture format (Mesa workaround)` option but it's not there on screen capture.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do the logs say? Do you use pipewire? BTW: Instead of logging out you could also simply reboot.

Comment: @mashuptwice Are the logs inside the terminal I've opened obs with? I don't think I use pipewire but I'm not sure (might have installed it as a dependency while programming but unlikely) rebooting doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure that a 5 years old answer on ubuntu doesn't work with bleeding edge stuff on debian like wayland, hence the BTW. You can find the logs in the menu bar -> help -> logs. About pipewire, you can check with `pactl list | grep pipewire`.